# Convert Curl to Java

Tags: java, android, curl, parse-platform

I am having trouble converting this to Java. So the `curl` line is

```
-d '{"skills":{"__op":"AddUnique","objects":["flying","kungfu"]}}' \
```

Normally what I do to a `curl` command such as this:

```
-d '{"score":73453}' \
```

would be:

```
httpRequest.setContent("{\"" +
           "score\": 73452 "+
           "}");
```

Comment: Did you try doing what you normally do? What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what your issue actually is but a reasonably straight forward way to match that command in Java is this:

```
String url = "whatever.your.url.is";
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();

connection .setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
connection .setRequestMethod("POST");
JSONObject json =new JSONObject();
JSONObject skills =new JSONObject();
skills.put("__op", "AddUnique");
skills.put("objects", new JSONArray(Arrays.asList("flying", "kungfu"));
json.put("skills": skills);
OutputStreamWriter wr= new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
wr.write(json.toString());
```

Comment: You are awesome :)! I wasn't sure if i could use JSON.